Valgrind Massif - startpoint for memory allocation [cpp]
I just started getting in touch with Valgrinds massif tool and wanted to know, if one could introduce a checkpoint to start monitoring the heap allocation.
Considering the following basic example:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int  nrOfElements= 10; 
    uint32_t *a[nrOfElements]; 

    for(int i=0; i<nrOfElements; i++)
    {
         a[i] = new uint32_t(i);
    }

return 0; 
}

compiling it, running valgrind (valgrind --tool=massif --time-unit=B ./program) and executing ms_print massif.out.3***** returns the following memory table :

here we can see, that there is an initial heap memory allocation from the standard library of 72,704 Bytes. Since I am only interested in the memory allocation starting from the main, I was wondering how i could do that?
Is there something like a checkpoint, which one could introduce to monitor the memory allocation only in a certain area?

Massif doesn't have a mechanism to turn instrumentation on and off.
Take a look at the --ignore-fn= option, and specifically for your example --ignore-fn=call_init.part.0. You can repeat use of this option to filter out multiple functions.

An alternative solution is to use memcheck. The leak search functionality of memcheck allows to do "delta/differential" leak search, showing the increase/decrease between the previous leak search and the new leak search. See e.g. the description of the leak search monitor command in https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands

thank you guys!
Ignoring this one function already served my purpose. Thanks
